# How to refer to filename which stays partly constant - SSIS job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS job where vendor drops file weekly and my ssis job picks it up to process. I have defined variables in my SSIS job. One of the variables is for the file name as below.

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::carListFile].Properties[Value]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>carList07302015.csv</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

The file name will be changing date. How can I refer to filename in my job if only the date part is going to change. I know we can do it using asterisk(*) but don't know the proper syntax. Help needed :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this is to use a foreach loop that goes through all the files in your drop-off folder, and then use a script task to check if the file name matches whatever criteria you are looking for:  in your case, all but the date-part should match a certain string.   If it's a match, the script returns success and you store the file name in a variable and proceed with the import.   If it's not a match, the script reports failure and you skip the rest of the steps in the loop and look at the next file.